# TextView with clickablespan throwing exception on long click

Tags: android, textview, long-click

I've a TextView in my app where every word is a clickable span. Everything works fine until I long click any word, which throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.getMinTouchOffset()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Editor.touchPositionIsInSelection(Editor.java:917)
    at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1018)
    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9436)
    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5700)
    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:22431)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6372)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
```

I've tried setting android:longClickable="false" on the TextView but in vain. Any idea how it can be fixed?

Thanking in anticipation!

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I've tried setting longclickable property of TextView to false. That's all! Other than that, I've no clue about what's happening. Couldn't find anything on internet either.